# Can the cdk.context.json file be auto-generated for a specific CDK environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have inherited a small CDK project that features a `cdk.context.json` file:

```json
{
  "vpc-provider:account=9015xxxxxxxx:filter.tag:Name=preprod-eu-west-1:region=eu-west-1:returnAsymmetricSubnets=true": {
    "vpcId": "vpc-0d891xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "vpcCidrBlock": "172.35.0.0/16",
    "availabilityZones": [],
    "subnetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "Private",
        "type": "Private",
        "subnets": [
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0ad04xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.a.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-0fee4xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-08598xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.z.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-0f477xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Public",
        "type": "Public",
        "subnets": [
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0fba3xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.y.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02dfbxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0a3b8xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.x.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02dfbxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This works fine for the preprod environment it connects to, but I now need to deploy to production. I could generate the same file by hand, but this feels like a waste of time - I suspect this is a generated file.

I have tried `cdk context --build` in the hope that it would produce this file, but it seems not - it appears just to echo the preprod one that already exists. What can I do to avoid having to hand-build this (and to avoid all the guessing which VPCs and subnets it wants)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file is generated for whatever environment your CDK stacks are being deployed to.

If you want to populate it with values for both your staging environment and production, you should simply run `cdk synth` after activating your production AWS credentials (using `--profile`, for example). This will populate the context with new values (in addition to the ones that are already there), and you should commit these changes to VCS.

It is advised to keep the file in your VCS specifically to avoid having it re-populated on each deployment. This makes your CDK app deterministic.

From the [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps):

> **Commit cdk.context.json to avoid non-deterministic behavior**
>
> AWS CDK includes a mechanism called context providers to record a snapshot of non-deterministic values, allowing future synthesis operations produce exactly the same template. The only changes in the new template are the changes you made in your code. When you use a construct's .fromLookup() method, the result of the call is cached in cdk.context.json, which you should commit to version control along with the rest of your code to ensure future executions of your CDK app use the same value.

A better way to organize this would be to make your stacks environment-specific - that is, to instantiate your top-level stack or stage once for each environment you want to deploy to, specifying the `env` prop. Deploying then becomes `cdk deploy MyStaginStack` and `cdk deploy MyProductionStack`. Although this is off-topic for the question.

Comment: I have indeed committed this file, glad I am doing something right! I have presently hand-generated a simple version of the context file, which seems to go through `cdk synth` correctly (I don't have the credentials myself, but I do have access to a run pipeline that does). I will see how far I can get with this hacky approach, but `--profile` will be next on my radar. Thanks for the post!

Comment: Yeah, you definitely don't have to (and I'd say shouldn't) populate the file by hand. CDK does it all for you.

Comment: I tried `--profile` on its own, looks like it needs a param. The syntax help in the error says it needs a `$LD_PROJ_KEY` - I don't think that is set in my env, and I am not sure what one looks like. A quick search says it relates to Launch Darkly, which we do use, but there is none of that in this project...

Comment: The help line says "Use the indicated AWS profile as the $LD_PROJ_KEY environment".

Comment: Ah, I think Bitbucket is monkeying around with "secrets" output - it should say "Use the indicated AWS profile as the default environment"! `:=)`

Comment: I don't know if I have a profile or what one is. Based on the docs I was hoping it would update the context file simply from a synth without `--profile`, but it did not. Does the `cdk.context.json` file have to not exist in order to be created? I wonder if it is not being overwritten because it exists already (which is silly, since it should just update it with a new environment key and all of the relevant objects, like VPCs and subnets).

Comment: You don't have to use a profile - just run `synth` with the production credentials and the context file will be populated.

Comment: Nice one. I have a synth pipeline in prod, and that didn't seem to write the file as you describe. I will give it another go though. With my hand-populated file I get: "VoucherSupportStack failed: Error: VoucherSupportStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/xxxxxx/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)".

Comment: More stuff to investigate `:-p`

Comment: Admittedly I get "current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::$CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT:role/cdk-xxxxxx-lookup-role-$CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT-eu-west-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.", so perhaps that just means someone set up the wrong creds.

Comment: (I will ask a new question about bootstrapping, as I am veering off the purpose of this page).

Comment: My related question, if perhaps you might be interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251144/is-cdk-bootstrap-safe-to-run-on-a-production-system

Comment: This can happen if you production environment is not bootstrapped (as suggested in the error message).

Answer (score -2):

This file is auto generated per deployment.  You should exclude this file from your code repo.

### Update

Some folks have commented to say that the file should be committed to keep deployments deterministic. I think this depends on your environment.

The context file is get updated as you synth for different accounts/environments. I came across a scenario where deployment was unsuccessful as the lookup is returning incorrect value from the context. The setup in the project did not have options to use profile in deployment. Commit from CICD pipeline was not allowed. So, it is really the restriction you are working within the project regardless of what the best practices advises you. I can generate it from my private sandbox account which I did not want to commit the for client account.

Comment: This is not good advice. It is advised to commit the file to VCS specifically so that your CI/CD runner doesn't have to perform the lookups on each deployment and to achieve deterministic behavior. Refer to my answer for more details.

Comment: Nabarun - I am grateful for your answer, but the feedback here says that it is not ideal advice. Is it worth deleting it?

Comment: @halfer depends on your environment.  The context file is get updated as you synth for different accounts/environments.  I came across a scenario where deployment was unsuccessful as the lookup is returning incorrect value from the context. The setup in the project did not have options to use profile in deployment. Commit from CICD pipeline was not allowed.  So, it is really the restriction you are working within the project regardless of what the best practices advises you. I can generate it from my private sandbox account which I did not want to commit the for client account.

Comment: Righto. I wonder if that is a relevant caveat that could be edited into the answer?

Comment: I know this advice goes against general approach, but Nabarun has a good point, if i'm looking up my instances from a cdk.context.json file which is really just a hardcoded approach, then how will it deal with changes in my environment ? might as well just hard code the id's in my cdk

Comment: One thing I'm still trying to reconcile is why Amazon has this file in their gitignore in the CDK examples repository?
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/.gitignore#L378

Comment: @user2612665: I assume that where important environment variables change, one would do a one-off update commit to the context file. This would allow deployments to remain deterministic, while taking env changes into account.