# Is `cdk bootstrap` safe to run on a production AWS system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have inherited a small AWS project, and the infra is built in CDK. I am relatively new to CDK.

I have a Bitbucket pipeline that deploys to our preprod environment fine. Since it feels reliable, I am now productionising it.

I detailed on [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73249557/can-the-cdk-context-json-file-be-auto-generated-for-a-specific-cdk-environment) that there is no context in the project for the production VPCs and subnets. I have been advised there that I can get AWS to generate the context file; I have not had much luck with that, so for now I have hand-generated it.

For safety I have made the deployment command a `no-execute` one:

```
cdk deploy --stage=$STAGE --region=eu-west-1 --no-execute --require-approval never
```

In production I get this error with the prod creds:

> current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::$CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT:role/cdk-xxxxxxxx-lookup-role-$CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT-eu-west-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
> Bundling asset VoucherSupportStack/VoucherImporterFunction/Code/Stage...

I then get:

> ❌  VoucherSupportStack failed: Error: VoucherSupportStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/xxxxxxxx/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)

I am minded to run `cdk bootstrap` in a production pipeline, on a once-off basis, as I think this is all it needs. We have very little CDK knowledge amongst my team, so I am a bit stuck on obtaining the appropriate reassurances - is this safe to run on a production AWS account?

As I understand it, it will just create a harmless "stack" that does nothing (unless we start using `cdk deploy ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to bootstrap every environment (account/region) that you deploy to, including your production environment(s).

It is definitely safe to do - it's what CDK expects.

You can scope the execution role down if you need (the default policy is `AdministratorAccess`).

Although your pipeline shouldn't ideally be performing lookups during synth - the recommended way is to run `cdk synth` once with your production credentials, which will perform the lookups and populate the `cdk.context.json` file. You would then commit this file to VCS and your pipeline will use these cached values instead of performing the lookups every time.

Comment: Thanks again - great stuff. This bit in the docs is excellent, and very reassuring: "It is not an error to bootstrap an environment more than once. If an environment you bootstrap has already been bootstrapped, its bootstrap stack will be upgraded if necessary; otherwise, nothing happens."

Comment: This meant that I could run the bootstrap on preprod, and it completed basically as a no-op. This is a nice confidence boost in terms of knowing it is going to tear anything down!

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, but here some extension to @gshpychka answer:

You don't have to bootstrap your production environment in case you are deploying your application with [AWS Service Catalog](https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/). The setup in our project looks like following:

- Resources account - for pipelines, secrets, ...
- Development account - bootstrapped, the dev pipeline deploys directly to this account
- Integration Account and Production Account - not bootstrapped, we are provisioning the releases and the release candidates through the AWS Service Catalog.

Service Catalog provides the cool functionality to provision and also update the applications in a friendly way. There are [CDK LVL2 stable constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_servicecatalog-readme.html) for building Your product stacks.

Of course, this approach has its advantages and disadvantages. I would recommend using it if you want to have full control over when you want to deploy or update your application. It is also worth using this approach if you are developing an application that will be installed on a client account.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wanted to do the minimum possible, as using CDK was already going out on a limb - my team is a Serverless shop really, for good or ill, and selecting a new technology may introduce a new learning curve that we don't need. But you never know - perhaps CDK might be something we could incrementally move to without major disruption.